Launch sandboxed Java app on Mac at login
I have a Java application which must launch at login. This currently works by writing a plist file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents. I want to bring this app into the Mac Appstore and therefore need to apply the com.apple.security.app-sandbox entitlement. With this, the app is no more allowed to write to this directory.
I've read I should use SMAppService (in Objective-C or Swift) to make my app be launched at login. How can I use this (or the underlying) API from Java? (Or any other idea how I could launch this sandboxed Java app at login?)
